# CSS: How to have only 100% with fluid layout and border?

Tags: css, layout

I am trying to understand the basics of CSS layouting and have some problem with a page being too high when I add a border.

Here comes my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="KKF_00005.css">
<title>KKF 5: Border coping</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="links_aussen">
        <div class="innen">Rechts</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mitte_aussen">
        <div class="innen">Mitte</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rechts_aussen">
        <div class="innen">Links</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I use the following stylesheet:

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

* {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html,body {
    background-color: grey;
    width: 100%;
}

.innen {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.links_aussen {
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
}

.mitte_aussen {
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100%;
    width: 34%;
}

.rechts_aussen {
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 33%;
}
```

And here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tt13/997zC/)

My problem is that this code gives me a nice 100% layout horizontally but creates a scrollbar being to high verticcally. I would like to have no scrollbars but also see the borders (so overflow: hidden; will not help me in this one I think) - tested in Chrome and Firefox.

So: How can I tell my little browser that it should remove 2 pixels from the height so that I can have borders and no scrollbars?

Thanks in advance for any ideas and answers
André

Comment: You should have a look at the [box model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)

Comment: Why do you use ISO-8859-1? Is there ever any resin not to use UTF8?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reminder :-) I had a day of with the family so I will add my answers now.

Comment: The ISO stuff was a default in Eclipse. Thanks for pointing it out. I will change that in the future.

Comment: I will take a look into JSFiddle. It will be better to put the code in there and only have the critical stuff pointed out. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution for you using `box-sizing: border-box`. It also removes the need for the `.inner` div.

http://jsfiddle.net/mqchen/xHFvG/

EDIT: If anyone is wondering why this works, look down at Joakim Johansson's post. Now, back at this post. The `box-sizing` property simply redefines how the browser calculates the size of elements. More about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing

Answer (score 3):

This is because the default box model is content-box, and works like this:

[image: From w3schools]

The heights you set changes the "Content" part. So if you have height set to 100%, and border set to 1%, that will add up to 101%.

This is solved in different ways depending on what you're trying to do.

For example you can set the box-sizing attribute: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html to make the height attribute work in different ways.

Can't for the life of me figure out a good solution right now (since relying on box-sizing isn't that compatible), but here's a bad one, using absolute positioning: http://jsfiddle.net/XhfmR/

Comment: Hi, thanks for explaining the problem. I picked the solution above as my solution as it was nearer to what I was looking for. But I rate your answer up.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is borders:

Instead of

```
.innen {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tt13/997zC/

Use

```
 .innen {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black; 
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tt13/997zC/1/

When you write just `border` it adds borders to all sides of div. In your case, bottom and top border takes extra 1px, you're getting result 2px taller in height. That's why you see scrollbar.

And always use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for this kind of questions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the anwser but it did not solve my problem actually. I wanted the borders on the upper and lower side. Thanks anyways for taking the time answer.

Comment: @AndreKuntze you think someone will pay attention to 1px border on the upper and lower side?

Comment: Hi, I am just practicing deliberately and trying to understand how things work. So I asked this question to understand what is happening - maybe I never use it but I understand box-sizing now ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
.innen {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

is your problem. It creates the vertical scrollbar.
To solve this, use this code:

```
.innen {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yrLtz/

Edit: Maybe the best solution is `box-sizing: border-box` as @mqchen suggested.

Comment: Sadly `box-sizing` isn't available on all browsers and if it is you need a prefix... :( So your answer is a good solution, too.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the anwser but it did not solve my problem actually. I wanted the borders on the upper and lower side. Thanks anyways for taking the time answer.